# Дружба сериализации QT и NET

Tags: .net, qt, сокет, tcp

Необходимо осуществить обмен между клиентом и сервером(сокеты).
Сервер на QT, а клиент на NET.
Передавать хочу опкод->сообщение. С клиента отправляю так:

```
serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(opcode)  
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)
serverStream.Write(outStream, serverStream.Length, outStream.Length) 
serverStream.Flush()
```

На сервере принимаю так:

```
QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();
readCommand->read(Data);
QDataStream stream(&Data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
quint16 command;
QString message;
stream>>command>>message;
qDebug()<<command<<"-"<<message;
```

Но сервер воспринимает все полученное как command. Вопрос! Как подружить сериализацию из .NET с сериализацией из QT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
serverStream.Write(outStream, serverStream.Length, outStream.Length)
```

Если serverStream - это Stream, то второй параметр - это смещение в массиве outStream (который на самом деле не stream, а byte[]). Ваш код передает туда ненулевое смещение -> начало outStream, т.е. начала message теряется.

Строки в QT скорее всего null-terminated. Результат же преобразования на C# - не null-terminated. Поэтому QT воспринимает весь буффер как сплошную строку.

Но проблема даже не в этом. Сокет - это труба с непрерывным потоком данных. Если вы делаете две записи в него - не факт, что на другой стороне данные придут двумя кусками. Точно так же, не факт что записанное одним куском дойдет точно так же одним куском. `socket->readAll` вычитывает то, что успело дойти - и это не обязательно целая пара команда + сообщение. Это тяжело заметить на одной машине, но как только вы запустите это на разных машинах - сразу же пойдут "порванные" на несколько кусков строки.

Если вам нужен надежно работающий механизм - сначала передавайте длину всего, что собираетесь отправить:

1. Длину команды
2. Саму команду
3. Длину сообщения
4. Само сообщение

И на сервере вычитывайте сначала длину каждой строки, а потом ровно столько байт, сколько ожидается.

Comment: К сожалению мне что-то стукнуло в голову, что смещение идет относительного того что уже есть там. Якобы каждый новый Write без flush перед ним перезаписывает все что уже положено в стреам.